# XML SOAP Creation

Tags: xml, soap

I am trying to create a SOAP request to send file through web request. I am 100% new to this process.

Could you please help me to start with this please?

Comment: Since a language has not been specified for this question, I don't think it is answerable in its current form, and needs to be closed.

Answer (score 0):

You need a webservice endpoint. You create one of these by defining a class with the @WebService annotation. Besides that, you need to set up a WSDL. You can either write one yourself or have the web server create one based on the @WebService class and the @XmlElement data objects. These @XmlElement classes are the actual interface classes which will contain the data you send and receive.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Would it be poossible for you to provide an example please?

Comment: I've already made a stay with the tutorial. I would be able to get the first few pages up in a day or two

Comment: @SomaGhosh:  Ok, I've just put up the first 4 parts of the tutorial. These should get you started well enough. http://www.coding.ractoc.com/soap-webservices-with-maven-part-1/. I'm still working on the Client generation as well as a few pages on some more complex topics like naming conventions and restriction. These will come in the next few days.